# Read in csv and convert all times

Tags: python, csv

I have a csv like so:

```
Name, TIME, TIME, TIME, TIME, Something, TIME, TIME, TIME, Something....
```

I want to take all the TIME column and convert them using

```
datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(TIME).strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
```

I'm trying the following

```
def transform_date(TIME):
    return datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(TIME).strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')

def transform_row(row):
    return row[0] + [transform_date(row[1])]  + [transform_date(row[2])] + [transform_date(row[3])] + [transform_date(row[4])] + row[5] + [transform_date(row[6])]+ [transform_date(row[7])] + [transform_date(row[8])] + row[8:]

name = 'FakeAPData.csv'
bakname = name + '.bak'
os.rename(name, bakname)
with open(bakname, 'rb') as csv_in, open(name, 'wb') as csv_out:
    writer = csv.writer(csv_out)
    writer.writerows(transform_row(row) for row in csv.reader(csv_in))
```

How do I make transform_row better?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`map`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#map):

```
return ([row[0]] + map(transform_date, row[1:5]) + 
        [row[5]] + map(transform_date, row[6:]))
```

This will apply the function to each item in turn and return a list (in Python 2.x - in 3.x it's an iterator) of the results.

---

Alternatively, make `transform_date` deal with the case that it can't process the input, and apply to the whole `row`:

```
def process_item(s):
    try:
        return datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(s).strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
    except ValueError:
        return s

def transform_row(row):
    return map(process_item, row)
```

Comment: Trick is, `row[5]` apparently is not supposed to be transformed because it's not a date. (I'm not your downvoter.)

Comment: Yes Fred is correct otherwise, map would be the best solution.

Comment: But you could probably map on the two slices that are to be transformed. It would still clean things up a bit.

Comment: Apologies, didn't spot that. I have edited my answer accordingly

Comment: The second solution allows for the general case so that you do not have to worry about which column is not a date. I would say that is better.